# Почему не только первый бит равен 1 у отрицательных чисел?

Tags: java, битовые-операции, binary, int

Недавно узнал, что первый бит в двоичной кодировке числа отвечает за знак: 1 ≡ - и 0 ≡ +. Однако, если использовать форматирование строк под 32 символа-бита (как в int) и в цикле вывести n-e количество отрицательных чисел, то мы увидим, что не только первый бит будет равен 1, а и последующие; причём в таком виде не понятно даже, где начинается само число, тогда как для положительных чисел всё, очевидно, выводится нормально.
Соответственно, вопрос, почему так? И как бы мне получить запись для условной цифры 
 -7 ≡ 111 (2) или любой другой не: 11111111111111111111111111111001 (вообще не понятно, **что откуда взялось**? **:)**, но это типа **7**), а в таком виде:
10000000000000000000000000000111.
Ниже прилагаю простенький код для теста:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Char {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //int x = random.nextInt(1000);
            int x = -random.nextInt(1000);
            String binaryNumber = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
            binaryNumber = String.format("%32s", binaryNumber.replace(' ', '0'));
            System.out.println("x = " + x + " (10)");
            System.out.println("x = " + binaryNumber + " (2)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4). Вкратце: если от 0 отнять 1, то все биты становятся 1. Если еще вычесть 1, то самый правый бит становятся 0, остальные остаются 1, и т.д. Можно было бы и просто одним битом менять знак числа, но через дополнительный код арифметика проще.

Comment: От души, уважаемый! ;) А есть в Java простой рецепт/метод, как получить именно 10000000000000000000000000000111 для условной 7-ки или любого другого числа? Не прописывая инверсию получения дополнительного кода.

Comment: Простого рецепта нет, только извращения через инверсию и битовые операции

Comment: Понял, принял. Спасибо и всего вам хорошего! :)

Comment: Дополню еще почему арифметика проще: с точки зрения бит сложение с отрицательным числом в дополнительном коде не отличается от сложения с положительным числом (за счет переполнения - лишние старшие биты результата просто отбрасываются). Если бы менялся только один бит, то нужна была бы дополнительная проверка знакового бита. Благодаря дополнительному коду есть микросхема "сумматор", но нет микросхемы "вычитатель")

Comment: `есть микросхема "сумматор", но нет микросхемы "вычитатель"`. Correction: "вычитатор". Простите, не удержался :)

Comment: @kami, но и его тоже нет)